Merge Struct column in delta table using spark
How to apply merges to the struct column nested fields in the below table. An existing row in the employee table has structData column with STRUCT datatype and stores data with nested fields. When an update to existing row id comes, a MERGE INTO query updates the id, firstName & lastName columns. In addition, I want to merge the columns in structData nested column. For example, the table is defined as below:
CREATE TABLE employeeTable(
  id String, 
  firstName String, 
  lastName String, 
  structData STRUCT<>
);

Contents of firstFileForInsert.json
{
    "id": "Profile_00",
    "firstName": "Bill",
    "lastName": "Titan",
    "Emails":
    [
        {
            "emailId": "EM00_1",
            "emailAddress": "somefineemail@awesomenews.com"
        },
        {
            "emailId": "EM00_2",
            "emailAddress": "ben@amazingnews.net"
        }
    ]
}

Merges the data from inputFile to delta table
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.delta.schema.autoMerge.enabled","true")

df = spark.read.json("s3://bucket/firstFileForInsert.json")
df = df.withColumn("structData",F.struct("*"))
df = df.select("id", "firstName", "lastName", "structData")

df.createOrReplaceTempView('inputFile');

spark.sql("MERGE INTO employeeTable pst USING inputFile ip on pst.id = ip.id WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET pst.firstName = ip.firstName, pst.lastName = ip.lastName WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT *")

Since the table was empty, the records were inserted as the matching condition for update did not meet:
+----------+---------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id        |firstName|lastName|structData                                                                                         |
+----------+---------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Profile_00|Bill     |Titan   |{[{somefineemail@awesomenews.com, EM00_1}, {ben@amazingnews.net, EM00_2}], Bill, Profile_00, Titan}|
+----------+---------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Data in Delta table:
Data in Delta table
When an update to the record comes in, how can I write merge into to update the array inside stuctData in addition to the other columns in the table.
For example: Update to exsiting row id of Profile_00 comes in and the Merge Into sql condition will match to update firstName and lastName; how can I write the Merge Into to match on emailId values between the inputfile and delta table and update existing rows and if not present insert those.
Contents of SecondFileForUpdate.json
{
    "id": "Profile_00",
    "firstName": "Bill",
    "lastName": "Pondarosa",
    "Emails":
    [
        {
            "emailId": "EM00_1",
            "emailAddress": "Updated-somefineemail@awesomenews.com"
        },
        {
            "emailId": "EM00_2",
            "emailAddress": "ben@amazingnews.net",
            "domain": "amazingnews"
        },
        {
            "emailId": "EM00_3",
            "emailAddress": "ben_pondarosa@amazingnews.net"
        }
    ]
}

Expected result in Delta table after Merge:
+----------+---------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id        |firstName|lastName|structData                                                                                         |
+----------+---------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Profile_00|Bill     |Pondarosa   |{[{somefineemail@awesomenews.com, EM00_1}, {ben@amazingnews.net, EM00_2,"domain": "amazingnews"},{"emailId": "EM00_3","emailAddress": "ben_pondarosa@amazingnews.net"}], Bill, Profile_00, Pondarosa}|
+----------+---------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

How can I write the Merge into query to match on the fields inside nested columns and update or insert elements at that level in addition to at the parent level. I tried writing MERGE INTO with fully qualifying column names but to no avail as it compares the complete array instead of comparing each element in the array. It will be great if anyone can point me in the right direction how to achieve this.
Many thanks in advance!
